# How do I delete messages from MSMQ using the Computer Management tools in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, msmq

Computer Management -> Services and Applications -> Message Queues

How to delete a message from a specific queue?
It seems to me there was some way but I cannot find it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it isn't possible to delete a poison message by MMC.

You can try [QueueExplorer](http://www.cogin.com/mq/download.php) and maybe that will help you out, or you have to programmically to solve your issues

Comment: There is also MSMQ Studio http://www.geekproject.com/tools.aspx but I take this as an answer.

Comment: Seems MSMQ Studio is no longer maintained

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10 you can empty a queue in Computer Management --> Services and Applications --> Message Queuing by right-clicking the queue and selecting All Tasks --> Purge:

[image]